# How to add Underline/Bold/Italicize Abilities for UITextView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have been searching for quite a while for a solution as to how to grant users the ability to underline, italicize and bold text in a `UITextView` but have not been able to find a solid solution. I have realized that I will need to use an `NSAttributedString` but am not sure as to how to create the `UI` and format the string so I am able to save it to a database. If you could point me in a proper direction that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The UI is simply an ordinary editable UITextView with `allowsEditingTextAttributes` set to `true`.

How you save is up to you, but the most universal solution is probably to pull out the UITextView's `attributedText`, archive it into an NSData (now known as Data in Swift), and save it off.

Comment: Why not save the attributed string as RTF data (Using the `NSAttributedString` method `rtf(from:documentAttributes:)`, to a file with the extension .rtf? Such a file can be opened directly from a text editor.

Comment: I don't believe `rtf(from:...)` is available on iOS. It's an AppKit extension. (Have I missed it somewhere in iOS all these years?)

Comment: @DuncanC He said "in a database". I don't know what that means, but any "database" I can think of will accept Data.

Comment: Point taken. Missed that bit.

Comment: @RobNapier rtf support was added in iOS 9 or so. A welcome addition to be sure.